# Android - Change font specific area on textview (xml side)

Tags: android, textview

I want to change font specific area on textview. But xml side, not code.

How can i do that. Thanks.

Comment: Font specific area? Can you elaborate?

Comment: this is a test sentence. i want to do bold "sencence" word

Comment: Andros's answer might come in handy

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. 
It's possible via code using either SpannableString, TextView with html (Html.fromHtml()), or with a WebView.